# Are there any papers explaining how to port textbook RSA to realworld RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, algorithm-design, reference-request

Are there any papers, books, or link where it explains how the plain vanilla "textbook RSA" is actually implemented in practice with all the padding and stuff?

Basically, I would like to know the intricacies of implementing an algorithm into production level code…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vanilla textbook RSA does not include "padding and stuff", the term "textbook RSA" generally refers to simply encoding a plaintext message as an integer and raising it to an exponent. Implementing this is pretty easy, just follow the [steps outlined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Operation) on Wikipedia. You can easily translate those steps into some given programming language.

Based on the rest of your statement, it sounds like you want to implement a real-world encryption/signing scheme using RSA, but not some higher protocol that uses it. If so, I would suggest looking at [PKCS #1 v2](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125). It's an authoritative specification for several such RSA padding schemes. (RSA-OAEP is probably the most recommended padding scheme for encryption if that's what you want.)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to B-Con's correct answer, there is one additional thing you may need to worry about: RSA key generation.  Now, PKCS #1 doesn't discuss it; for formal advice on how to do that, you might consider [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf), and in particular, section 5.1 and appendix B.3.3.  Now, FIPS 186-3 discusses several possible methods for finding primes (which is the hard part in generating an RSA key); I selected B.3.3 as the easiest, if it isn't the fastest.